# How can I change CSS with JavaScript without the use of an ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scrollbar

I have a custom scroll wheel and I want to make a button to switch between two classes for that scroll wheel, for example let's say I have these CSS lines to style the scroll wheel:

```
    body::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 1em;
    }

    body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(180, 88, 88, 0.473);
      background-color: rgb(131, 69, 69);
    }

    body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgb(185, 115, 115);
    outline: 1px solid slategrey;
    }
```

But when I click the button I want it to change to this CSS:

```
    body::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 1em;
    }

    body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px DIFFERENT COLOR;
      background-color: DIFFERENT COLOR;
    }

    body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: DIFFERENT COLOR;
    outline: 1px solid slategrey;
    }
```

Everything I have read uses the ID to change the CSS for that element but I can't do that with a scroll wheel. I hope this explained it well enough please ask me if you want me to add more code, examples etc.

Comment: use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`. You can either use `querySelector('.class')` or if you want to target a tag `querySelector('tag')`. Also works with ID's by using `querySelector('#id')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just toggle a class on the body which changes the styling.

Below is an extra snippet that makes use of [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

```js
const changeBtn = document.querySelector('.change-btn');

changeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('changed');
});
```

```css
/* For demo purposes */
body {
  height: 500vw;
}

/* Default styling */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(180, 88, 88, 0.473);
  background-color: rgb(131, 69, 69);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(185, 115, 115);
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

/* Changed styling */
body.changed::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px orange;
  background-color: teal;
}

body.changed::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<button type='button' class='change-btn'>Change</button>
```

**Bonus with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)**

```js
const changeBtn = document.querySelector('.change-btn');

changeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('changed');
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vw; /* For demo purposes */
  --track-color: rgb(131, 69, 69);
  --thumb-color: rgb(185, 115, 115);
  --shadow-color: rgba(180, 88, 88, 0.473);
}

/* Default styling */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px var(--shadow-color);
  background-color: var(--track-color);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--thumb-color);
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

/* Changed styling */
body.changed {
  --track-color: teal;
  --thumb-color: lime;
  --shadow-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<button type='button' class='change-btn'>Change</button>
```

Comment: This is a better answer

Answer (score 1):

You can select elements on jquery without it's ID by using classNames, data-attributes, etc.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('body::-webkit-scrollbar').css({
        'width' : '1em',
        ...
    })
    $('body::-webkit-scrollbar-track').css({
        'background-color' : 'DIFFERENT COLOR',
        'another-property' : 'another-value'
        ...
    })
    $('.class-name').css({
        'width' : '1em',
        ...
    })
    $('[data-foo="bar"]').css({
        'width' : '1em',
        ...
    })
    $('.class-name.with-another-classname').css({
        'width' : '1em',
        ...
    })
    $('.class-name .with-children').css({
        'width' : '1em',
        ...
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not require ID's. The alternative to `getElementById`is the usage of `querySelector`. `querySelector` can be used to target classes, Id's or tags.

In your case the best solution however would be to target the body tag and to add a class to the body that applies your changes you predefine in CSS like the sample below:

```js
function addClass() {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('red');
}
```

```css
html {
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}

body.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addClass()">Turn background red</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to do it like this:

```js
function toggleBodyActive(){
  document.body.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
/* set bodyheight for scrolling */
body{ height:200vh; }

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
          width: 1em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(180, 88, 88, 0.473);
  background-color: rgb(131, 69, 69);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: rgb(185, 115, 115);
outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}


/* same but when body has .active class */

body.active::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

body.active::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 188, 88, 0.473);
  background-color: rgb(31, 169, 69);
}

body.active::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: blue;
outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="toggleBodyActive();">toggle 'active'</div>
```

Comment: ow.. more people suggesting same answer :)

Comment: as side note, if you want content for scrolling just use `min-height: 100vh+`. less "spam". also you proberly wanted a button instead of a div.

Comment: haha indeed, quick and dirty... but certainly one to keep in mind. tnx .  The div was intentionally btw. its just an element, buttons have the build-in action/states you dont always need/want. How many linkable elements are really 'buttons' nowadays...

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector for that
`document.querySelector('body')`